# Xcode 13.2 Image Slicing not working as expected when using mutliple apperances

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, vectorization, xcode13

I'm having difficulties with the image slicing functionality when using multiple appearances for my image.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I made two PDF's for an outlined button, one for light and one for a dark appearance.

When I create a new image set with appearances set to "None" and I slice the image everything  works as expected and the button can be resized without problems:
[image: slicing]
[image: test button with working slicing]

But in my app I want to support dark mode, so I want to have two versions of my outline:
[image: slicing multiple appearances]

But by adding the second appearance, the slicing now no longer works correctly, and the button now looks like this (but only when dark mode is on, light mode still looks the same):
[image: broken slicing button]

Is there anyone who had the same issue and found a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Unclear what the question is or what you want from Stack Overflow. File a bug with Apple.

Comment: I did so months ago, but the issue is still marked as "Open", doesn't seem to bother anyone. I was hoping to find a workaround.